# How can I use backslashes in variables in vim script?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

If I define a variable in vim script:

```
let path = "E:\mainVersion\GameServer"
```

and then echo it:

```
echo path
```

But I get this :

```
E:mainVersionGameServer
```

I think maybe it's because the backslash is an special character.
Here's my quertion:

1. Why the backslash(`\`) disappear?
2. How can I echo the entire variable?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

use single quote

```
let path = 'E:\mainVersion\GameServer'
```

then

```
echo path
```

another test:

```
let foo="a\nb" 
echo foo
```

output:

```
a
b
```

and:

```
let foo='a\nb'
echo foo
```

you will see: `a\nb`

With single quote those sequences will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Like in most languages, you can use backslash to escape those characters.

```
     :let path= "E:\\path\\subdirectory"
```